# Aligning name/value pairs from a prior command's ouput

Tags: bash

The `hostnamectl` command outputs some nicely formatted info that includes your hostname, but it doesn't include the fully qualified domain name (FQDN), as does `hostname -f`.

As a means of learning more about controlling bash output formatting, I'm wanting to combine these two commands into one command in a manner where the 2nd command adheres to the first command's output-alignment.

```
hostnamectl ; fqdn=$(hostname -f) ; echo -e "\t\tFQDN:\t${fqdn}"
```

Notice, however, that I wasn't able to align `FQDN:` consistent with the first sub-command's output.

Does there exist a command that would allow me to format the 2nd output base on the first output's alignment without scripting? I suspect not, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this with just spaces in my string: `hostnamectl ; fqdn=$(hostname -f) ; echo -e "              FQDN: ${fqdn}"`. Instead of literal spaces, I'm now looking for a command that would repeat the space character x number of times.

Comment: I found out how to repeat the spaces: `hostnamectl ; fqdn=$(hostname -f) ; spaces="$(printf "%0.s " {1..13})"; echo -e "${spaces} FQDN: ${fqdn}"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy with just statically setting the alignment, then you could do something like this:

```
hostnamectl ; fqdn=$(hostname -f) ; printf "%18s: %s\n" "FQDN" "${fqdn}"
```

The `%18s` specifier has `printf` print that string on a field 18 characters wide, right aligned. (`%-18s` would be left-aligned.)

You could also just realign all the output with e.g. awk:

```
(hostnamectl ; fqdn=$(hostname -f) ; echo "FQDN: ${fqdn}") |
    awk -F: '{printf "%20s:%s\n", $1, $2}'
```

(that's assuming there's only one `:` on each line)

Or, have the awk script check the position of the `:` on the first line and align everything to that:

```
... | awk -F: 'NR == 1 {w = index($0, ":")} {printf "%*s:%s\n", w, $1, $2}'
```

(Having a tool check the output of `hostnamectl`, and then provide the position of the colon to where you print the FQDN, *and* have the output to the terminal at the same time would require some messy redirection hell. It's far easier this way.)

Comment: Awesome answer! You've inspired me to learn more about `awk`. Thank you.